# Unable to create a new Alexa skill from command line - Invalid command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have installed `ask-cli` using the following command:

`sudo npm install --g ask-cli` and here is the output, which I don't understand much to be honest!

When I try to create a new skill using the following command:

```
ask new --template --url https://skilltemplates.com/templates.json
```

I get the following error message in the terminal:

```
[Error]: Invalid command. Please run "ask new -h" for help.
```

I opened the help (`ask new -h`) and it seems like my command is valid. Here is the output:

```
--template [template-name] create a skill project based on the chosen template
--url <url>                provide a customized list of templates
```

I am using `npm version 6.9.0` on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: This help may not be completely accurate. [Here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#new-command) it reads `ask new [--url <url> [--template <template name>]] ...`, as if `<template name>` was not optional after `--template` (but they both as a whole are optional); and probably `--template` must be after `<url>`. Just a guess, so not an answer yet.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! Unfortunately `ask new --url https://skilltemplates.com/template.json --template api-starter` is not working either. The error I am getting is `Invalid json: /home/subrara/.ask/cli_config`. I searched and there is no `.ask` folder under `/home/subrara` directory. There is an `ask` file though in `/usr/bin/` directory. Something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Just to be sure: did you check with `ls -a`? Sole `ls` won't show you `.ask` because it starts with a dot. Anyway, I believe my comment solved the original issue. What you're experiencing now is a new, probably unrelated problem. I don't know `ask` at all, so I'm not sure.